# how to start a Powershell Script from PHP and add Parameters

Tags: php, powershell, shell-exec

I need to Execute a Powershell Script with a Button via PHP
And i need to add Parameters and return them to php

```
echo Shell_Exec ('powershell -InputFormat none -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoProfile -Command  "& { . \"C:/Users/Alexl/Desktop/Schuljahr 19-20/Diplomartbeiten/Powershellscript/firstscript.ps1\";}" & -Temperatur 24 -Ort Leipzig ');
```

I tried this in a Button it starts the Script but didn't add the value 24 and Leipzig

param(
[decimal]$Temperatur = 18.0,

[string]$Ort = "Berlin")

```
Write-Host "Es sind $Temperatur grad C in $Ort."
```

It Just starts the Script and Returns " Es sind 18 grad C in Berlin
so it doesn't change the Variables Parameters...

Comment: OK so your problem is not with php but with the PowerShell script and passing parameters to it, right ?

Comment: Indeed maybe checking the documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-5.1&redirectedfrom=MSDN#parameters-in-scripts